# for loop in shell script to not display one specific number

Tags: shell, for-loop

Using a FOR loop in shell script I am trying to print numbers from 1 to 15 except for number 10. The below code gives me error :

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=1;i<16;i++));
do
if [ $i -ne 10 ];
echo $i
else
break
fi
done
```

> test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token 'else' test.sh:
>   line 7: 'else'

Could someone please help me here.

I checked the threads on for loop and couldn't find any such similar questions, hence posted this question.

Comment: Missing a lot of thing ... Try : for ((i=1;i<16;i++)); do if [ $i -ne 10 ]; then echo $i; else break; fi; done

Comment: thank you, this prints me numbers from 1-9 how to print the rest 11-15 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=1 ; i<16 ; i++ )); do 
    if [[ $i -ne 10 ]]; then 
        echo $i
    fi 
done
```

You forgot the `then` after the if conditional. Also, the `break` on the if statement will exit the loop if i = 10, thus not printing the numbers from 11 to 15 with just the code you've written.
Also, you could change, in this case, `[[ ]]` for simple `[]` on the if statement.
Be aware of spaces between symbols.

Comment: Thank you, the question I have is, the break statement would exit the if condition and not the for loop. Hence on i=10, break is encountered which will come out of if and not for loop. Hence shouldn't for continue from i=11 till i=15 ?

Comment: According to the bash manual, the `break` keyword is used for exiting "from a for, while, until, or select loop."

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..9} {11..15} ; do echo $i ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to print everything other than a given number, right. Are you trying something along these lines?

```
#!/bin/bash 
for ((i=1;i<16;i++))
do
if [[ $i -ne 10 ]]
then
echo $i
fi
done
```

This should print everything other than 10. I've not tested it but should work.